# SSRS 403 forbidden from .NET application

Tags: sql, .net, reporting-services

We have a .NET application that is already working in a number of development and production environments. One part opens SSRS reports, one new server is giving me this error when it tries to run. I have double checked the installation of our application and done a bunch of troubleshooting including reinstalling SSRS. Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot further?

> System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type
>   'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. --->
>   System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 403:
>   Forbidden.

Comment: Is it a Windows- or a Web-application? How is the user authenticating at the Report Server? How is authentication configured in the Data Source(s) of the report?

Comment: It is a web application, there are credentials specified in the web.config file that are passed through to SSRS using basic authentication. There is something weird in just this environment as it is working in seven other environments.

Comment: Ok, then check the configuration in the web.config, also verify that the report server is configured to support Basic authentication. If everything is configured correctly, try to open the report directly using the credentials specified in the web.config. Can you access the report that way?